# Can't add ref to windows store application since it targets .NET Core

Tags: windows-8, nuget, caliburn.micro

I've created a blank windows store app and there are plenty of tutorials for getting Caliburn Micro up and running using NuGet, so I'm following one of those

My issue is that when I try to add a reference to caliburn via the nuget console I get the following error:

`Install-Package Caliburn.Micro...`

...

`You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETCore,Version=v4.5'`

Apparently CM doesn't target .NETCore, only .NETFramework - fair enough but...

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be doing, as since it's a Store app, I thought it would only run off .NETCore - yet the articles I'm seeing suggest you can work with store and CM (and there are a few people on the CM forums that say that CM works fine). I can't change the target framework (it's greyed out)

I'm running VS2012 and a fresh install of Win8 (brand new lappy yay!) so I'm not sure what I'm missing...NuGet says it's up to date (2.6)

Any ideas? (probably something stupid...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - it seems even though NuGet was up to date it wasn't working properly...

I downloaded latest and it seems to have fixed the issue!